# Migration to any European country from Sri-Lanka with a medical condition

Tags: visa, working-visas, health

One of my friends applied to New Zealand migration a few years back and during the medical exam discovered that there was a kidney failure problem, so the application was rejected. Now it's been almost 3 years since the kidney transplant was done and monthly reports seem to show very positive results. My friend still takes medications daily and will for life.

Will my friend will be able to apply for migration again to any European country? Will they reject the application due to this medical condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rules and practices differ from one country to the other so it will be very difficult to provide a comprehensive answer. Some European countries (e.g. France or the UK) do require a medical exam for immigrant visas but as far as I know the focus is on a limited number of contagious diseases, especially tuberculosis.

For example, in the case of France, applicants should be up-to-date in their vaccines following French regulations (mostly relevant for children) and have to undergo a basic physical (including an X-ray of the chest but no blood test). Formally, the visa can be refused if a person is infected with one of the diseases listed in the WHO's 1969 International Health Regulations (that's the plague, cholera and yellow fever) or if they have TB or a mental ailment that make them dangerous to others and they refuse treatment. So it does not sound like your friend's problem would preclude him or her from getting a visa there.

That said, getting a visa is often very difficult, even for perfectly healthy people. You can expect a lot of bureaucracy and arbitrariness and unless your friend falls into some specific category (e.g. highly qualified professional or family member from a citizen), it's virtually impossible to get a long-stay visa for the European countries I know about.